# Bootstrap burger menu shows on small screen but doesn't fold back on second click

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, azure

I have a page that unfold the very standard menu system when shown on smaller screen. So I assumed that the Bootstrap was up and running nicely. However, after the burger menu has been opened, it's not possible to fold it back by a clicking again on the button.

I haven't been able to reproduce the issue in a fiddle, so I uploaded it to an [Azure website](http://donkeymanualdeploymenttest.azurewebsites.net/). I'm getting the same result running locally and both on FF and Cr.

Googling gave nothing of value. The only thing I've noticed was that if I click a third time, right after the second click, there's an error in the console saying that the collapsing is currently in progress. So it seems that the JS is running but that the rendering can't make the class to be updated to be hidden. executing the class assignment from the console does hide the menu, though.

I'm out of ideas. Suggestions?

NB: it's Bootstrap 4 alpha 6 and Angular 4.

**Edit:** As requested, the markup of my navbar.

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-inverse bg-primary navbar-toggleable-sm">

  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" 
          data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsee">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Donkey</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsee">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: can you provide the html for your menu? I've got a bootstrap 4 alpha 6 navbar up and running, I'd like to compare to see why yours may not be cooperating

Comment: Could've be your implementation of the navbar? I don't want to say silly things, but does it work sometime?

Comment: @Vega Sometimes, the most silly questions will resolve the most complicated issues. The navbar behaves consistently, i.e. it always unfolds and it ever folds back. Tested on a myriad of browsers, a few different computers, both locally and served, over a course of time and numerous redeploys. Very, very consistent. I'll post the HTML of my navbar in a few minutes - feel free to take a looky-looky.

Comment: I tested the link on both Crome and safari and their responsive design modes, and everywhere it fails to close, indeed. Could be the bug, as quoted above ?

Comment: @Kevin As requested - my navbar's markup.

Comment: @Vega Posted. I cut out some elements to make it shorter and redeployed. Still - the same issue remains...

Comment: Have you imported the jquery dependencies? (in case...)

Comment: @Vega Yes, I have. I can confirm that I have because the menu opens (functionality is there) and won't open when I remove the linking tag from *index.html*. Can you confirm that yours fold after unfolding?

Comment: I understood that after posting by comment... And I confirm that it Doesn't fold!! :(

Comment: I am thinking of class name collapsing!! check for that please. It is often the case with bootrstrap, you use the same names as bootstrap classes and it fails to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your menu div to this could work, and adding in a click event for the button:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" (click)="toggleState()" type="button" 
          data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsee">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" [ngClass]="{ 'show': isIn }">
```

and the typescript function:
isIn = false;
....

```
toggleState() {
        const bool = this.isIn;
        this.isIn = bool === false ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach: +1. Will try it out.

Comment: Let me know how it goes, shaking with excitement from the anticipation of your response

Comment: When I tried out your suggestion, I actually found another issue I wasn't aware of. It made me realize what was colliding with the jQuery package to begin with, so now the issue is gone all together.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6 to Bootstrap 4.0.0-beta that is pre-released and available at this link [Release v4.0.0-beta](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/tag/v4.0.0-beta).